# Managing Static Data Items in entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having my Domain models as below

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
}

public enum Skills
{
    JAVA,
    DOTNET,
    PYTHON
}
```

I am trying to model the entity framework models as -

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skills
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Skill { get; set; }
}
```

Skills are restricted to one of the few value types. When Entity framework creates the tables, it is creating a Foreign key in Skills table on the EmployeeId PK. Essentially every entry in Employee table will have one or more entry in Skills table. Again, if the Skills is referenced in another entity, another column would be added to store the key referencing it.
I am not sure if this is the right way. Is there a way to limit the Skills table to only the static data and have a join table? What would be the best practice for managing the relations with Static data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have classical Many-to-Many relationship: one employee can have many skills and a skill can be possessed by many employees. EF Core does not support implicit Many-to-Many relationship as EF6 does, so you need to introduce intermediate entity. Your model will be looking like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skills
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Skill { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeSkills
{
    public long SkillsId { get; set; }
    public Skills Skills {get; set;}

    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee {get; set;}
}
```

In DbContext composite key should be set up for the intermediate entity and Skills data can also be seeded there.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSkills>(e =>
        {
            e.HasKey(l => new { l.SkillsId, l.EmployeeId });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Skills>(e =>
        {
            e.HasData(new[]
            {
                new Skills() { Id = 1, Skill="JAVA" },
                new Skills() { Id = 2, Skill="DOTNET" },
                new Skills() { Id = 3, Skill="PYTHON" },
            });
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so this would create an entry in Skills table, for each Employee. I was wondering if there is a way to limit the Skills to only the data elements. Not sure if that is the recommended appraoch.

Comment: In the proposed solution you have 3 tables Employee, EmployeeSkills and Skills, for adding new skill to the employee the new entry in EmployeeSkills table is created. Adding data to Skills table is the responsibility of your application logic and you can make this table read only.

Another solution is clumsy and inefficient, but if the number of skills is limited to an enum, you may store list of skills of each employee as a comma-separated string of values, e.g. employee.Skills = "JAVA, PYTHON". In that case your enum will be a golden source of available skills and table is not required.